# How to apply envelope modifier to F-curve in Blender 4.0?

Tags: rendering, animation, fcurves

How to apply envelope modifier to F-curve in Blender 4.0?

Has it been moved somewhere else?

Comment: I see it in 4.0.2.  Exactly as in 3.6.5